# Heroku deployment error: Cannot find module '../databaseInstance/CarModel"

Tags: node.js, api, express, heroku, deployment

[Build was successful but cant find module error came](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwttZ.png)

[But Every thing is ok in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikRNL.png)

Need Solution how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I got Answer
I accidentally wrote CarModel instead of carModel . Thats why it throw module not found error. Heroku is camelCase sensitive. Keep it on mind this error lost my 2 hours  time